# How do you put a conditional statement inside of a SQL count?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have some entries where the join date and transaction dates are the same, so I want to include a condition excluding  if the count is zero (divide by zero case). I was wondering if I could include it within the COUNT statement.

I've tried the below and other slight variations attempting to include a conditional.

Here is a small segment of my code:

```
SELECT 
...
    d.revenue / COUNT((DATEDIFF(day, c.join_date, d.transaction_dates)) <= 90)
...
```

As explained above, this is the error:

Invalid operation: Divide by zero

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name AWS

Comment: This question is too vague. Please specify what database engine you are using. And if it isn't Athena or Redshift this question probably shouldn't be tagged with `aws`.

Comment: @MarkB it is redshift

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry I was not familiar with the term DBMS. I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep this syntax. Your query is incorrect after your first then.

```
   CASE
        WHEN condition1 THEN result1
        WHEN condition2 THEN result2
        WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
        ELSE result
    END;
```

Comment: I commented out the entire case statement and my query ran just fine for whatever reason @Y.Y. I only have problems when including the case. I just shared my entire select statement below:

Comment: `SELECT 
 COUNT((DATEDIFF(day, c.join_date, d.transaction_dates)) <= 90), 
 COUNT(c.cust_id),
 r.item,
 CASE
       WHEN COUNT((DATEDIFF(day, c.join_date, d.transaction_date)<= 90) > 0 THEN d.revenue_off_sale/ COUNT((DATEDIFF(day, c.join)date, d.transaction_date)) <= 90)
    END
... `

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement

```
Select 
...
 Case When Count(foo) > 0 Then bar/count(foo) 
 Else 'skipped' End as ColumnAlias
...
```

Comment: I still receive an error: Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "THEN". You happen to see anything here???   ```CASE 
  WHEN COUNT((DATEDIFF(day, c.agr_tier_eff_dt, d.lift_dt)<= 90) > 0
  THEN d.TOT_RVNU_AMT / COUNT((DATEDIFF(day, c.agr_tier_eff_dt, d.lift_dt) /* AS DateDiff */ ) <= 90)
 END ```

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis `)` before the `<=90`